# Как сделать, чтобы телеграм-бот пересылал сообщения из чатов мне?

Tags: python, telebot

Идея состоит в том, чтобы бот, добавленный в беседу, мог по команде переслать сообщение лично ко мне в чат/в другую беседу. Допустим, пересыл будет зависим от того, есть ли рядом определенное слово или нет и т.д.

Я перепробовала пару кодов, которые находила здесь, либо логичные, по моему мнению, миксы составленные мной из них же, но чаще всего оно чуть отдалено от моей идеи, либо PyCharm выдает мне, что есть ошибки, которые я не понимаю.

Я буду рада пометкам для наглядности и понимания...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот пример на aiogram:

```
# Обработчик команды /forward
@dp.message_handler(commands=['forward'])
async def forward_message(message: types.Message):
    # Проверяем наличие указанного слова в сообщении
    if 'важно' in message.text.lower():
        # Отправляем сообщение в другой чат с помощью метода forward_message
        await bot.forward_message(chat_id='TARGET_CHAT_ID', from_chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.message_id)
        await message.reply('Сообщение переслано')
    else:
        await message.reply('Отсутствует ключевое слово, пересылка не выполнена')

# Запускаем бота
if __name__ == '__main__':
    dp.start_polling()
```

В чем тут соль?
В том, что бот будет смотреть на каждое сообщение, и если найдет в нем искомое, то отправляет тебе в личку.
Думаю, на надо говорить, где ты можешь достать свой id?